# Prevent specify folder to build by postcss

Tags: javascript, vite, postcss

I want to prevent specify folder to build by postcss. I have vite, postcss.config.js and few of folders created by another people. So i want to configure my postcss.config to build only my folder (with env variable). Here is my code segments

postcss.config.js

```
import * as path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { dirname } from 'path'

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = dirname(__filename)

export default (ctx) => ({
  map: true,
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {
      path: path.resolve('src/assets/styles')
    },
    'postcss-mixins': {
      mixinsDir: path.resolve('src/assets/styles')
    },
    'postcss-extend': {}, // plugin for Sass-like variables
    'postcss-simple-vars': {}, // plugin for Sass-like variables
    'postcss-nested': {}, // plugin to unwrap nested rules like how Sass does it
    'postcss-color-function': {}, // plugin to transform CSS color function from editor draft of 'Color Module Level 4' specification to more compatible CSS.

    // https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer
    autoprefixer: {
      overrideBrowserslist: [
        'last 4 Chrome versions',
        'last 4 Firefox versions',
        'last 4 Edge versions',
        'last 4 Safari versions',
        'last 4 Android versions',
        'last 4 ChromeAndroid versions',
        'last 4 FirefoxAndroid versions',
        'last 4 iOS versions'
      ]
    },
    tailwindcss: {
      config: path.join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js')
    }
  }
})
```

default.config.ts

```
import { Module } from 'module'
import * as path from 'path'
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import { createSvgIconsPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-svg-icons'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { viteSingleFile } from 'vite-plugin-singlefile'
import DefineOptions from 'unplugin-vue-define-options/vite'
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import fs from 'fs'

export default defineConfig(async ({ mode }) => {
  const env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) }

  let context
  let code
  let images
  if (env.VITE_VARIABLES) {
    code = env.VITE_VARIABLES.replace(/.tsx/, '')
    try {
      context = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `./packages/shared/scheme/public/${code}`))

      const data = await Promise.all(context.map((image) => {
        return fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `./packages/shared/scheme/public/${code}/${image}`))
      }))

      images = data.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
        acc[context[index]] = `data:image/${context[index].split('.').pop()};base64,${btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(item)))}`
        return acc
      }, {})
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('defineConfig error:', e)
    }
  }

  return {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@pages': path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/pages/'),
        '@shared': path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/shared/'),
        '@assets/': path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/assets/'),
        '@': path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src'),
        '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './packages/ui-components-v2')
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      vue(),
      vueJsx(),
      svgLoader(),
      viteSingleFile({
        inlinePattern: ['**.js']
      }),
      createSvgIconsPlugin({
        iconDirs: [
          path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/assets/icons'),
          path.join(__dirname, 'packages/ui-components/assets/icons/common'),
          path.join(__dirname, 'packages/ui-components-v2/assets/icons/common')
        ],
        symbolId: 'icon-[dir]-[name]',
        inject: 'body-first'
      }),
      DefineOptions()
    ],
    define: {
      global: 'globalThis',
      'process.env': {
        ...env,
        APP_CODE: code,
        APP_IMAGES: JSON.stringify(images)
      }
    },
    base: './',
    build: {
      cssCodeSplit: false,
      assetsInlineLimit: 100000000,
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          format: 'iife',
          inlineDynamicImports: true,
          manualChunks: undefined
        }
      }
    },
    server: {
      open: true
    }
  }
})
```

I have spent a days for it, please help